# Query information from SQLite database in android by Date

Tags: android, sqlite

I want it so that when the user selects a date my SQLite database only shows the information from that date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on how you are storing the date information.  If you are storing it as a string like "2012-01-19 16:20:00" then you can just fetch them with this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_time LIKE "2012-01-19%" ORDER BY event_time;
```

in Android you may do some thing like this:

```
String[] whereVars = new String[] {"2012-01-19%"}; 
String where = "event_time LIKE ? "; 
dbHandle.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM event WHERE " + where + " ORDER BY event_time", whereVars);
```

Comment: I get an error `01-20 13:31:36.857: E/AndroidRuntime(11151): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ORDER": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT* FROM wwlltdTable WHERE JobDate LIKE 2012-01-19% ORDER BY JobDate`

Comment: The problem was with the % sign as soon as I took that out the I did not get a force close but nothing showed up.

Comment: You forgot the quotes around the date string

Comment: @frast, It wont let me put quotes around it.

Comment: Which editor are you using? Can you edit the SQL statement directly?

Comment: @frast, I am using android sdk in eclipse

Comment: I do not know how to do it with android sdk. May be single quotes work?

Comment: @frast, I did try that but it says `no such column: 2012-01-19`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6906/discussion-between-frast-and-christian)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select * 
from myTable 
where myDateColumn between (Date(myDate, 'localtime'), date(myDate,'localtime','+1 day')
```

[Here's more info:](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)